# C find all occurrences of substring

Tags: c

Is there an **efficient** way to find all occurrences (including overlapping) of non const `char *str2` in `char *str1` and outputting the numbers position of matches in str1 in C (not in C++ as it differs)?

Comment: Do you need overlapping or non-overlapping occurrences?  Are you aware of `strstr()`?  What have you tried?

Comment: It sounds like you need strstr().

Comment: I need including overlapping and I'm not aware of strstr()  ;)

Comment: How long is the string we're talking about? If it's really long, you might consider some pre-processing for fast operation afterwards. Same goes if the string changes infrequently and is queried often.

Comment: Here's a reference for [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) — yes, that's POSIX, but for this function, it matches the C standard exactly.  You need to learn which functions are in the standard C library and how to use them.  Then questions like this become easy.

Comment: I saw this reference, but it finds only 1 occurrence and I'm not sure if it's faster in some algorithm then for example this method [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)

Comment: Try it and see.  It depends on what you're doing, and how often you're doing it, but I'd lay odds that for many purposes with a single scan through the data, the cost penalty of building a Suffix Array outweighs any performance benefit in the (one time) search phase.  If you're going to be repeatedly analyzing the data, possibly with different strings, then pre-processing may provide a big win.  But for most naïve applications, they're unlikely to help.

Comment: If `str2` is constant and you want to find it in several `str1`, a string search algorithm like Knuth-Morris-Pratt or Boyer-Moore can be a win over `strstr`, also for pathological cases if you're only scanning one `str1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will use [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) in a `while` loop to find the first match of `str2` in `str1`.  You can then print the offset of that match.  You'll continue the search at the first character after the match. You'll stop the loop when `strstr()` no longer finds a match (signalled by `strstr()` returning NULL).

If you needed non-overlapping, you'd want to know the length of `str2` and you'd start the next search at the matched character plus the length of `str2`.

Comment: That's okay, but I'm looking for more efficient algorithm e.g. suffix array, because `str1` can be really long and program execution time is limited

Comment: Try `strstr()`; it can be hard to beat.  At least on Mac OS X, I tried BM and KMP in C and didn't get close to `strstr()` in performance.  I was both surprised and disappointed.  Are you doing 'bioinformatics' searching on ACGTAGGTCA type strings?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`strstr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) inside a loop:

```
int get_substr_count(const char * haystack, const char *needle)
{
    int count = 0;
    const char *tmp = haystack;
    while( tmp = strstr( tmp, needle)){
        printf( "Position: %d\n", (int)(tmp-haystack));
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: That counts the matches; it's not the same as printing the positions of the matches.

Comment: you should increment tmp inside while loop, else this code goes to infinite loop because it keeps searching from same index.

Comment: You should increment tmp with strlen(needle), because after the first occurrence of needle, strstr will return the tmp reference and it goes to infinite loop.